# How to get rid of the line connecting the points when loop starts again?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have data in my hand which consists of 26 millions of row (Temperature and Depth). Temperature is measured till the equipment reaches 12000 meter and then it starts again (Of course each time it gets different values for the temperature). I know that this question was asked before but this case is a bit different. I cannot simply delete the loop but I need to get rid of that line somehow:

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

x = []
y = []

with open('DTS.txt', 'r') as csvfile:
    next(csvfile)
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    try:
        for row in plots:
            x.append(float(row[1]))
            y.append(float(row[2]))
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        pass
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.title('DTS results between 21-26th of June')
plt.xlabel('Depth')
plt.ylabel('Temperature')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: You will want to append a `numpy.nan` or `None` to the data where the line-break should take place.

Answer (score 0):

By default `plot()` plots a blue line connecting your data points, so you can try to specify what you want the function to do.

try something on the line of
`plot(x,y, linestyle = "", marker = "o")`

this should replace the line with dots hopefully getting rid of the line, without breaking the loop.

alternatively you can look at the [scatterplot function](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html)

As general comments:

- please check the matplotlib `plot()`
  [page](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot)
  for syntax and arguments for graphical settings
- provide a minimal example with data to reproduce the error. My answer is a guess, without sample data I can't test the solution